# openssl verification on PHP server error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: php, openssl, in-app-billing

wondering if anyone can help, I've seen this error in a few places but still don't have it resolved. When I'm trying to verify a payment from an in app purchase, I pass the variables to a server to validate there too, along with the app but I'm getting the following error:

> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

My code is below. Any suggestions?

```
// $public_key is the public key sent from the android app
// $signature and data are also sent via http to the server from the android app which were received from google.

$key =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n".
chunk_split($public_key, 64,"\n").
'-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$key = openssl_get_publickey ( $key );
$signature = base64_decode ( $signature );

$result = openssl_verify ( $signed_data, $signature, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1 );
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?